# Simulating a click on dom element

Tags: javascript, jxbrowser

Using jxBrowser I want to simulate a click on an html element using a code like

```
final DOMDocument dom = browser.getDocument();
Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>() 
{
 @Override
 public void invoke(Browser browser) {
    DOMElement elementToClick = dom.findElement(By.xpath("some xPath expression"));
    if (elementToClick != null) {
        elementToClick.click();
    }
}
});
```

This works fine if the click() action causes a page to download but if the click is just executing some javascript (with no network actions), I got a timeout exception.
So my question is how can I wait a click action is done when it is executing either "pure" javascript or web access.

Thank you for your help.

Regards,
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

The DOMElement click() method is asynchronous and JxBrowser doesn't wait until any action on the webpage caused by this method is finished.

I suggest that you can use some JavaScript solution to click the DOM element programmatically. The executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue() method of Browser instance is synchronous and will wait until all JavaScript event listeners which handle the click action on this DOM element are executed. Nevertheless you still should check if Browser is loading for the case when click action causes page loading.
Please take a look at the code sample below:

```
browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("document.getElementById('converted some xPath expression').click();");
```